# MySQL, order by multiple columns cause index fail

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

desc table ta, tb:

```sql
create table ta (
    id bigint primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(20) default ''
);
create table tb (
    id bigint primary key auto_increment,
    aid bigint references ta,
    home varchar(20) default '',
    index tb_aid (aid)
);
```

load test data, size of ta 400k , size of tb 200k

sql A cost-time 3s

```sql
select *
from ta left join tb on ta.id = tb.aid
order by ta.id desc, tb.id desc
limit 10
```

sql B cost-time 74ms (just remove`, tb.id desc`):

```sql
select *
from ta left join tb on ta.id = tb.aid
order by ta.id desc
limit 10
```

explain A:
[image: explain sql A]

explain B:
[image: explain sql B]

how can I improve sql A speed?

Comment: Try index `tb (aid, id)`.

Comment: I try instead tb_aid with `index tb_aid_id (aid, id)`, get same result, mysql version  5.7.22. thx for response

Comment: Does LEFT joining is needed really? maybe INNER joining is enough?